# color different values in leaflet from .tif file in R

Tags: r, leaflet

Hi i have tif file which looks something like this ,

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3500, 7000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent      : -130, -60, 20, 55  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : TT.tif 
name        :         max 
min value   :   0.8032204 
max value   : 256.7943726
```

i want to do leaflet map where i can able to color different values between min and max in different colors

my code till now :-

```
tile_layer <- raster(raster_tiff_file_path)
m <- leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng = mean(extent(tile_layer)[1:2]), lat = mean(extent(tile_layer)[3:4]), zoom = 10) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addRasterImage(tile_layer, maxBytes = 50000000)
```